# Is there any way to make this accesibile without breaking everything

Tags: css, accessibility, user-experience

I'm trying to solve an accessibility issue without making any breaking changes to an application.

In order to comply, the nav, header and main must be on the same level. Problem is, the nav and a wrapper for the header and main are rows in a flexbox (and have large amounts of custom css), and the header and main are columns in said wrapper.

[image]

Is there any simple way to bring everything on the same level without changing the layout? Everything I could think of requires pretty significant changes to the code.

Comment: You want to create the same layout?? Like shown in the image??

Comment: @KunalTanwar Yes, I don't want the layout to change, otherwise it would be trivial.

Comment: You would need to share the CSS and HTML as a minimal example for us to have a chance of helping you. At the moment nothing appears to be wrong with this, `div` elements have no semantic meaning and so your structure is essentially fine (from the diagram given). Who has told you there is a problem? Is the tab order incorrect? Do you have a page we can go to to test against if you can't create an example?

Comment: I agree with @GrahamRitchie. It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do here. It's unclear to me what "on the same level" means in this context. Are you trying to make a single-column layout for mobile? It would be helpful to have HTML/CSS examples so that we can understand what your current structure is.

Comment: @Josh I'm just trying to fix some issues reported by axe. Screen readers typically expect your website to have a specific structure. By "on the same level", I meant that in the html tree, they are at the same depth. I'll add some code for context.

Comment: I'm not aware of any requirement to have `<header>`, `<nav>` and `<main>` all at the same level in the DOM tree. The most restrictive of these is `<main>`, which cannot be a  child of an article, aside, footer, header or nav element.  Header and nav have no such limitations, although header does apply semantic meaning to the parent sectioning element. I believe that nav can be placed anywhere on a page that navigation controls appear.

Comment: @Josh Hm, fair enough. I don't know much about accessibility so I was going by what axe was reporting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grid` plus `flex` and do something like this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside, div, header, main {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

.wrapper aside {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper aside.left {
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper aside.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper aside header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.wrapper aside main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="left"></aside>
  <aside class="right">
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
  </aside>
</div>
```